# Checking username: getpwnam / getpwnam_r: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, passwords

I'm trying to make a web logging and I use **getpwnam()** function to check username existing. But for valid username **getpwnam** returns error: No such file or directory. So I tried **getpwnam_r()**, but it also failed with the same error. I'm running on embedded arm linux and I use */etc/passwd* for password storing (I don't have */etc/shadow*). My **test** program is:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct passwd pwd;
    struct passwd *result;
    char *buf;
    size_t bufsize;
    int s;

   if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s username\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   bufsize = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);
    if (bufsize == -1)          /* Value was indeterminate */
        bufsize = 16384;        /* Should be more than enough */

   buf = malloc(bufsize);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   s = getpwnam_r(argv[1], &pwd, buf, bufsize, &result);
    if (result == NULL) {
        if (s == 0)
            printf("Not found\n");
        else {
            errno = s;
            perror("getpwnam_r");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("Name: %s; UID: %ld\n", pwd.pw_gecos, (long) pwd.pw_uid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Password file can be written only by root:

```
/ # ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           207 Jan  1 00:29 /etc/passwd
/ #
```

I also tried to run my program (**test**) with root rights, but it also failed when I gave it an existing username.

```
/ # /tmp/test admin
getpwnam_r: No such file or directory
/ #
```

1) So, what I forgot about, or what should do additionally?

2) Do I need to use */etc/shadow* file for storing passwords for system users?

---

**Update:**

My passwd file is:

```
~ # cat /etc/passwd 
root:b6MVch7fPLasN:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/ash      
admin:8Mt/Jtxcyg8AY:1000:1000:admin:/tmp:/tmp/cli 
user:5v4HoPrA9NtUo:1001:1000:user:/tmp:/tmp/cli
~ #
```

Thanks in advance! Bakir

Comment: `No such file or directory` is printed for `ENOENT`, which might be returned if the given `name` does not exist. So are you sure you are testing this with a valid account name?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I even add new user with **adduser** command, but got the same result. Maybe I need change or add some other files in /etc directory? My passwd file is: ~ # cat /etc/passwd
root:b6MVch7fPLasN:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/ash
admin:8Mt/Jtxcyg8AY:1000:1000:admin:/tmp:/tmp/cli
user:5v4HoPrA9NtUo:1001:1000:user:/tmp:/tmp/cli
~ #

Comment: What `bufsize` are you actually using? You might like to print it out.

Comment: My bufsize = 1024 bytes.

Comment: Add a `printf("user: '%s'\n", argv[1]);` just before the call to `getpwnam_r()` and see what it'll give you.

Comment: And you can run strace for your program (`strace /tmp/test`) to see whats going and whats failing.

Comment: @ _alk_ => Yes I did print out username, it's ok. It's seems to be some incompatibility or shortage (file/lib). It's also interesting to look at source code of the **getpwnam**. @ _osgx_ => I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: I installed **strace** to my fs and checked my **test** prog. In the strace log I saw that my program couldn't get these files /etc/nsswitch.conf, /lib/libnss_compat.so.x, /lib/libnss_files.so.x. I added only "compat" lib and then program found specified username :) I'm happy! Many thanks @ _osqx_ and @ _alk_.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The search service or method used in the password database (*/etc/passwd*) is defined in */etc/nsswitch.conf*. To use this service **getpwnam** function calls shared library in the lib directory: /lib/libnss_SERVICE.so.x, where SERVICE is the search method. In my case **compat** is default method because of absent of */etc/nsswitch.conf*. So, I was need to add libnss_compat.so.2 to /lib.

**strace** is useful thing!

Many thanks to **osqx** and **alk**!